# Regex - capture whole line and ignore date and/or time substrings in line

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to be able to capture *the whole line* and ignore dates and times in a text file, since Ill only be needing the non-date and time data. Here is a sample portion of the file:

```
----------01/01/01----------14:49:43-----
-----01/01/01 14:49----------------------
--------------------14:50----------------
-----01/01/01 14:51:13-------------------
------------------01/01/01---------------
```

The '-' means those are the important data. As you can see, the date and time can *both* be in the same line, located *anywhere* within the line, and the time can be HH:MM or HH:MM:SS.

Im really hoping to be able to use only 1 regex to match all lines for this, and retrieve the '-' data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your sample input covers all formats possible in your input, `\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d` would match all dates and `\d\d:\d\d(?::\d\d)?` all time substrings. An alternation built from these two would match any date or time substring:

```
\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d|\d\d:\d\d(?::\d\d)?
```

Just replace globally with an empty string all found patterns and you'll be left with the important data only.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OKokqq/1

Comment: That was a very helpful regex, thanks. But could I ask for 1 more bit? I was only planning to make a regex that also includes the important data, such that I dont have to use substitution. Do you have a full-line regex for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})|(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bgx1NR/2

Comment: Thanks, but Id also like to include the important data in the regex itself. Could you make one? Still new to the whole regex thingy, so my apologies